# HTML Input Box - Disable

Tags: html, input

what is the code to disable an INPUT text box for HTML?

Thanks

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

See the [W3C HTML Specification on the input tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html) for more information.

Answer (score 58):

```
<input type="text" required="true" value="" readonly="true">
```

This will make a text box in readonly mode, might be helpful in generating passwords and  datepickers.

Comment: Surely adding the 'required="true"' part to a readonly textbox in general is a bad idea. There could well be cases where that textbox doesn't get a value put into it. Then your form won't be submitted and there will be little the user can do about it.

Comment: This answer helped me start to discover the difference between disabled & readonly; readonly being what I ultimately needed to prevent user interaction but still submit the prior-entered value.

See http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html

Answer (score 10):

The syntax to disable an HTML input is as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="input_id" DISABLED />
```

Comment: RoBorg's answer is valid in XHTML also.

Comment: The HTML 4.1 Specification he directs to, has the same code as in my answer.

Comment: HTML 4.1 is outdated. XHTML has to be valid, so browsers display it more consistently from one to the other, as different browsers have different error-handling code for cleaning up after sloppy developers (and might not get it right).

Answer (score 9):

You can Use both disabled  or readonly attribute of input . Using disable attribute will omit that value at form submit, so if you want that values at submit event make them readonly instead of disable.

```
<input type="text" readonly>
```

or

```
 <input type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the posters question, and id probably better suited as a comment to one of the other answers, or re-written to include the new point of the disable attribute

Comment: @stuart-siegler: I guess it does. However I've added the example.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" required="true" value="" readonly>
```

**Not the.**

```
<input type="text" required="true" value="" readonly="true">
```