# How to prevent user to type into a particular form field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and it has several fields. There is an ID field which is generated from another form. Now i want to prevent users to change that field value.

How do i do this? DO i need any javascript or anything else?

Comment: Google would have been a lot faster ya know

Comment: And would've brought you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372604/html-input-box-disable) :)

Comment: @adarksun well on a serious note, You should show some efforts before asking question as it is harmful for SO(some say but i think GC of SO is quite well) and for yourself too, I already flagged it (no downvote though) and i suggest you to be more proactive.

Comment: http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/

Answer (score 4):

You can use `disabled` on the field:

```
<input type='text' disabled />
```

Or `readonly`

```
<input type='text' readonly />
```

Comment: I think, it should be better to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: @Flea777 either is fine. In fact no quotes are necessary in this case.

Comment: There is no difference in using single or double quotes. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="NAME-OF-FIELD" value="VALUE-NOT-TO-CHANE" disabled="disabled" />
```

or you could use

```
<input type="text" name="NAME-OF-FIELD" value="VALUE-NOT-TO-CHANE" readonly />
```

or if you need to hide it

```
< input type="hidden" name="NAME-OF-FIELD" value="VALUE-NOT-TO-CHANE" />
```

You will still have access to it when you submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the HTML, I'd suggest making the input hidden with `type="hidden"`.

If you can't, apply the CSS style `display:hidden` to it.

Or did you want to leave it visible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the field:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

Or set it readonly

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A **readonly** element  not editable, but gets sent when the form submits. a disabled element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit.**Readonly** elements can be focused while disabled elements can't.

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```